# Extract rows with max value that has unique cell values

Tags: excel

The unique values are B, D, and F. I want to extract rows with a max Value in C. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Here is the sample value
[Sample Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqYE5.png)

Expected Output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnEhs.png)

This should be the expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more suited to [**SuperUser**](https://superuser.com/) because it's not programming-related but here's a quick answer.

If you want to display only rows where `Column C` = `Maximum of Column C` then you can use AutoFilter.

1. Select (highlight) the range to filter - in your example that's `B3:F6`.
   Click `Filter` on the `Data` tab to turn on AutoFilter.
   [image: img]
2. Click the arrow [image: Filter] drop-down arrow in the column header for column C.
3. Click `Number Fiters` -> `Top 10...`
4. Choose `Top 1 Items` and click OK.

[image: img]

Only rows with Column C = max(column C) will be displayed.

---

### More Information :

- Office.com : [**Quick start: Filter data by using an AutoFilter**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0)

Comment: Thanks , But the C cell can have also a 1 max value or 2, 3.. I want to get those rows too..

Comment: that doesn't make sense.  Maximum = largest.  You need to give more information, and examples representative of what you have and what you need, and be prepared to show what you've tried

Comment: You will noticed that B D E F cells has different values. I want to get the max C values for each rows with same B D E F values.

Comment: I added screenshots for the expected output.